# Why does this print the correct result in python 2x

Tags: python, string

```
print 'The value of pi is ' + str() + '3.14'
```

This will throw an error with int() and float() but not with str()
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do? What do you think `int()` / `str()`  / `float()` do / are used for?

Comment: You created an empty string object. You can concatenate strings. When you use `int()` or `float()` you create objects of a different type which cannot be concatenated with strings. I'm not sure where the confusion lies here.

Answer (score 3):

Because writing `str()` is equivalent to writing `''`, i.e. an empty string. With the `+` operator, you can either use it to add numbers or you can use it to concatenate strings together. When you try to add a string to a non-string, it won't work.

Your code is equivalent to the following:

```
print 'The value of pi is ' + '' + '3.14'
```

Which, in turn, is equivalent to:

```
print 'The value of pi is 3.14'
```

---

Using `int()`, your code is equivalent to this:

```
print 'The value of pi is ' + 0 + '3.14'
```

And with `float()`:

```
print 'The value of pi is ' + 0.0 + '3.14'
```

Neither of these will work because they try to add a string to a number.

---

You might have meant to do this instead:

```
print 'The value of pi is ' + str(3.14)
```

This converts `3.14` from a float (number with decimals) to a string, so that in can be concatenated with the string `'The value of pi is '`.

Comment: Thank you David, this is all new but it is a lot of fun. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

`str` cannot concatenate with `int` or `float` objects

```
>>>int()
0
>>>float()
0.0
```

Both are not `str` objects.But `str()` results a str object`''`.So it can.